# Do we have to restart webserver everytime we made changes?

Tags: reactjs

I've just cloned a repo from [github](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter), and started the server and able to see the default text showing at http://localhost:8080

The default text is showing inside `src/components/app.js`. And making any changes to the text, simply switch back to browser and reload the webpage to see the changes.

Now I try to create the `src` folder from scratch, so I've deleted `src` and recreated it and added a file `index.js`, without any content. (My web server is still running all this while)

So my question is, when I reload the webpage, I was expecting no content to be showing in the webpage. But truth is I can still see the previous changes showing on webpage. It seems to be cached or something? In order to reflect the latest changes, I have to kill the webserver and `npm start` again.

This is my first timer in Web Development so wondering if it's a common scenario and best practices to restart webserver everytime we make any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when developing with react you don't even have to refresh the page you are in. Once you save the changes in the Editor they sould be visible in the browser immediately. Maybe you have made a mistake by setting up the index.js

When starting with react I would suggest you to use https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

With that it's very easy to start and you can play around a bit and get started with React.

Comment: I'll surely try that out, maybe the repo I've cloned from was kinda old and hence the hot-reloading feature wasn't available back then

Answer (score 1):

You should use Hot Module Replacement.

Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
if (module.hot) {
module.hot.accept();
 }
```

Hot Module Replacement (HMR) is a tool to reload your application in the browser, so that the
browser doesn’t perform a page refresh.
BTW @Zander is right, you don't have to kill the server. The page automatically refreshes. For your help, I hope you installed create-react-app using npm as 
**npm install -g create-react-app** and to initiate a new app as **create-react-app yourApp**. If done so, everything basic is automatically configured.